# Server-localization for strings managed within the Application class

Tags: android, kotlin, localization

I'm developing an app with server-localized strings, and I want to use this localized string across my entire app.
So I came up with the following approach and would like to know if it will cause me any issues, or is there any better practice I can follow.

**My Approach:**

- Let my android `Application` class implements `Localizer` interface defined as follows:

```
interface Localizer {
    // get the localized string version for a given string key
    fun getLocalizedValue(key: String): String?
}
```

```
class MyApplication : Application(), Localizer {

    var localizedStrings:Map<String,String> = emptyMap()

    override fun getLocalizedValue(key: String): String? =
        localizedStrings[key]
}
```

- **In Splash Logic:** fetch my localized strings from server, and fill `localizedStrings` with the fetched (key,value) items.
- **And then:** use `MyApplication` class as a `Localizer` object across the app.

- Following is a sample code for a custom `LocalizedTextView` that utilizes the 'Localizer' interface the way I mentioned:

```
class LocalizedTextView : AppCompatTextView {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {
        initAttrs(attrs)
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context,
        attrs,
        defStyleAttr) {
        initAttrs(attrs)
    }

    private fun initAttrs(attrs: AttributeSet?) {
        if (attrs == null) return

        val styledAttrs = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.LocalizedTextView)

        val textKey = styledAttrs.getText(R.styleable.LocalizedTextView_localized_text)
        text =
            if (context.applicationContext is Localizer)
                (context.applicationContext as Localizer).getLocalizedValue(textKey.toString())
            else textKey.toString()

        styledAttrs.recycle()

    }
}
```

Comment: `or is there any better practice I can follow.` not really relevant to your question i suppose, but seeing as though you said it, what does `__t` mean ?? why is `val a = context......` context assigned to a variable called `a` ? this doesn't help anyone understand what you're doing - use descriptive variable names so that they actually mean something, to you _and_ to others reading it in future. would you want to be assigned to a project where you had to figure out what random letters mean all day ?

Comment: Your feedback is appreciated, it makes sense. I edited the code in the question.

Comment: other than that, i think your general approach is correct, just make sure your service request for the strings complete before you start making use of the application, otherwise things will be empty/blank

Comment: Yes that's right, the scenario before my service called is handled properly.